# Selecting range of data on hidden sheet without .Activate

Tags: vba, excel

I'm populating a combobox list via a hidden worksheet ("Data") where I have a few lists stored.

I currently select the range as below:

```
Dim arr() As Variant

Worksheets("Data").Activate

arr = Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

cboBox.List = arr
```

However, this obviously activates the hidden sheet "Data". How can I select that same range without selecting/showing the hidden sheet?

I tried using variants of...

```
arr = Sheets("Data").Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
```

... to avoid having to activate the sheet, but that doesn't work.

I think it's to do with calling the "D2" range twice for xlDown then xlToRight but I can't work out what the correct syntax needs to be.

Many thanks.

EDIT: YowE3K's suggestion worked:

`arr = Sheets("Data").Range("D2", Sheets("Data").Range("D2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))`

Comment: A variant that you **nearly** came up with, which would work, would be `arr = Sheets("Data").Range("D2", Sheets("Data").Range("D2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))`, but it is easier to write that using a `With` block as per @SJR's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could shorten that to

```
arr = Worksheets("Data").Range("D2").currentregion
```

or do it thus

```
with Worksheets("Data")
    arr = .Range("D2", .Range("D2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
end with
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I didn't think of that... I've even done that further down in my code...